# "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended" Exception in this piece of code

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to connect to the Oracle 19c database from Java. Connection is done and successful.
I'm running same query in SQL Develeper and it's working .But I'm getting exception in prepared Statement and executeQuery() in Java. Please help me out.

```
       Connection con=null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;

        try{
        
        //Loading Driver
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); 
        //Loading Connection
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl",dbUsername,dbPassword);     
        
        //Executing query;
        System.out.println("Connection Established");
        //Object to store result
        items=new ArrayList<Object>();
        
        queryString="SELECT * FROM HOMESQUAD WHERE EMP_MOBILE_NO='8308856606';";
        System.out.println("Query: "+queryString);
        if(queryString != null && !queryString.trim().equals("")) {
            System.out.println("Into P Statement If Loop");
            pstmt=con.prepareStatement(queryString);
            System.out.println("StateMent Prepared: "+pstmt.toString());
            rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("Query Executed");
            while(rs!=null &&rs.next()) {
                items.add(constructLoginProps(rs));
            }
            if(rs !=null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if(pstmt!=null) {
                pstmt.close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception Occured in aDBExecute:"+e.getMessage());
    }

    //constructLoginProps Function

    private HomesquadEmployee constructLoginProps(ResultSet rs) {
            HomesquadEmployee vo=new HomesquadEmployee();
            try {
                if(rs.getString("EMP_PASSWORD")!=null) {
                    vo.setEmpPassword(rs.getString("EMP_PASSWORD"));
                }
                if(rs.getString("EMP_ID")!=null) {
                    vo.setEmpId(rs.getString("EMP_ID"));
                }
                if(rs.getString("EMP_NAME")!=null) {
                    vo.setEmpName(rs.getString("EMP_NAME"));
                }
                if(rs.getString("EMP_MOBILE_NO")!=null) {
                    vo.setEmpMobileNo(rs.getString("EMP_MOBILE_NO"));
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception Occured in buildLoginQuery: "+e.getMessage());
            }
            return(vo);
    }

    //HomesquadEmployee Class
    public class HomesquadEmployee {
        private String empId;
        private String empName;
        private String empMobileNo;
        private String empPassword;
        public HomesquadEmployee() {
        }
        public HomesquadEmployee(String empId, String empName, String empMobileNo, String empPassword) {
            this.empId = empId;
            this.empName = empName;
            this.empMobileNo = empMobileNo;
            this.empPassword = empPassword;
        }
        public String getEmpId() {
            return empId;
        }
        public void setEmpId(String empId) {
            this.empId = empId;
        }
        public String getEmpName() {
            return empName;
        }
        public void setEmpName(String empName) {
            this.empName = empName;
        }
        public String getEmpMobileNo() {
            return empMobileNo;
        }
        public void setEmpMobileNo(String empMobileNo) {
            this.empMobileNo = empMobileNo;
        }
        public String getEmpPassword() {
            return empPassword;
        }
        public void setEmpPassword(String empPassword) {
            this.empPassword = empPassword;
        }
    }
```

---

Output:

Connection Established

Query:SELECT * FROM HOMESQUAD_EMPLOYEE WHERE EMP_MOBILE_NO ='8308856606';

Into P Statement If Loop

StateMent Prepared: oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper@51aeb3e7

Exception Occured in aDBExecute:ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had that problem once using an oracle database and I solved it by simply removing the semicolon ";" from the end of the query.
in your case you should change this

 `queryString="SELECT * FROM HOMESQUAD WHERE EMP_MOBILE_NO='8308856606';";`

for this

```
 queryString="SELECT * FROM HOMESQUAD WHERE EMP_MOBILE_NO='8308856606'";
```

Comment: I'm glad to read it, the first time I ran into this error it cost me a couple of hours.